# If $\int^b_a |\sin x|dx =8$ and $\int^{a+b}_0 |\cos x|dx =9$ find the value of $\int^b_a x \sin x dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Problem :

If $\int^b_a |\sin x|\,dx =8$ and $\int^{a+b}_0 |\cos x|\,dx =9$ find the value of $\int^b_a x\sin x \,dx$

My approach:

We need to find a and b here.

We know that $\int^b_a |\sin x|\,dx$ represents the area under the curve from x=a to x =b.

Also if we find the area from a to a$+\pi$ of $\int^{a+\pi}_a |\sin x|\,dx$ it is 2

But how we can find a and b here pleas guide it will be of great help thanks.

Comment: $b-a=4\pi$, $b+a=\frac{9\pi}{2}$.

Comment: To expand on the comment of @AndréNicolas -- you said yourself that $\int \limits_{a}^{a + \pi} |\sin{x}| \,dx = 2$, right?  Well, we have that $\int \limits_{a}^{b} |\sin{x}| \,dx = 8$.  But that means $b = a + 4\pi$, since $\int \limits_{a}^{a + 4\pi} |\sin{x}| \,dx = \int \limits_{a}^{a + \pi} |\sin{x}| \,dx + \int \limits_{a + \pi}^{a + 2\pi} |\sin{x}| \,dx + \int \limits_{a + 2\pi}^{a + 3\pi} |\sin{x}| \,dx + \int \limits_{a + 3\pi}^{a +4\pi} |\sin{x}| \,dx = 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 8$.  So, $b - a = 4\pi$.  Can you figure out the other equation he wrote?  It has to do with the $\cos{x}$ integral

Comment: Sultan, you ask so many questions but only accept answers to very few of them.  Is it really possible that you are continually dissatisfied with the answers you receive, or are you forgetting to mark an response that you feel answers your question as the "best" answer?

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is good. Note that in general
$$\int_c^{c+\pi/2}|\sin x|\,dx=\int_c^{c+\pi/2}|\cos x|\,dx=1.$$
It follows that $b-a=4\pi$ and $b+a=\frac{9\pi}{2}$. Solve for $a$ and $b$.